# variadic template and omp task

Tags: c++11, openmp, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am looking for a possible solution to wrap elegantly OpenMP task, specially the directives. In OpenMP tasks, argument must be pin with the key word `in`, `out` and `inout` like:

```
#pragma omp task inout(x) out(y)
plus_equal(x,y); // x+=y
```

Nice, however I am looking for an automatic solution to avoid to introduce directive for every functions, I am thinking with variadic template:

```
template<class Functor, class... Args>
void helper (Functor& f, Args&... args){
    #pragma in(SOMETHING), inout(SOMETHING ELSE) 
    f(args...);
}
```

Objectively the "glue" between the variadic template and the argument should be the `const` keyword if the argument is `const`: it is `in` else it is `inout`
or `out` (objectively there is no solution to distinguish `in` and `inout`) and then my code becomes:

```
helper(plus_equal, x,y);
```

Reading a few posts, it seems possible to extract argument of the variadic template, and it may be possible to extract argument between `const` and `non const` using `std::is_const`.
However I do not know if we can pass something not basic into the directive. I think it should be possible because, it is a macro.

However, I am not sure such solution exists.

Any idea ?

Best,

++t

Comment: This is an intriguing idea! Basically this could work, but 1) unless you can specify variadic arguments to the dependency lists, I think you'd have to do recursion and maybe chain some fake tasks with fake dependencies. Or maybe you could code-generate some generic "{in,out}^n" variations. 2) You could only use references and would have to be extremely careful about the lifetime of objects. 3) Just because your functor takes some arguments by `const` ref, doesn't imply the `const` on the argument to `helper`.